# What is the suggested method for migrating large Cassandra keyspace?

Tags: cassandra

What is the suggested method for migrating 500GB KeySpace from Cassandra v3 with 20 nodes to Cassandra v4 with 40 nodes? (copy/dsbulk/sstableloader/spark)

Thanks

copy/dsbulk/sstableloader/spark

Comment: why not simply do in-place upgrade with expansion before or after upgrade?

Comment: Add v4 nodes as a second DC (with proper replication in the keyspace), wait for the replication, launch a repair, shutdown the DC with v3 nodes

Comment: 20/40 nodes for a 500 GB Keyspace sounds a bit excessive TBH. If it weren't for fault tolerance I'd run that on one machine. Which leads to the question: Do you have some excessive replication factor going on for read performance or aggressive write volumes that would make the above mentioned approaches not viable?

Comment: @clunven We have different topologies in Cassandra v4 ,so we can't add v4 nodes .

Comment: @Tigraine This is not the only KS in the cluster. Can you please specify what you would run copy/dsbulk/sstableloader ? (  I can create a new machine with ssltableloader and run the load from that machine  )

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really have any experience with copy/dsbulk/sstable loader as we've gone the "extend cluster through DC" route so far. So not really comfortable giving advice on that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do a simple "file copy" because the source is not identical to the destination cluster. This method only works when both the source and destination clusters have identical configuration as I've documented in [How to restore snapshots to a cluster with identical configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316497/).

Exporting the data into CSV format then bulk-loading with DSBulk will work but it would be inefficient since it requires a full table scan. Similarly, doing it with Spark will also work but it still would not be optimal.

Using `sstableloader` is the recommended method for the following reasons:

1. The data is already in SSTable format so relevant fragments of each SSTable will be streamed to corresponding replicas in the destination cluster.
2. Data is read directly from disk making it more efficient than reading from the DB which requires serialisation/deserialisation on heap which is expensive.
3. The data does not have to converted into CSV format then eventually converted back to SSTable format via compaction.

For a step-by-step guide, see the procedure I previously documented in [How to clone data to a new Cassandra cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316520/). Cheers!